# Cut a convex polygon in two equal areas with minimum perimeter

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, polygons

Given a convex polygon. How to find a cut that divides the polygon in two equal area parts and the length of this cut is minimum.
Possible solution is 1. Find a minimum polygon projection. 2. Have found the cut direction  the cut position can be  find with a binary search.

Comment: Do you want the equal parts to have the same perimeter or the same area?

Comment: I mean the same area